A question on prime ideals in power series
While self-studying commutative algebra, I came across the following problem :
Let R be a commutative ring with identity. Suppose $I$ be a prime ideal of $R[[x]]$, then define $I_0 = \{ f(0) | f \in I \}$, then show $I_0$ is a prime ideal of $R$.
My approach was to show that $R/I_0 \cong R[[x]]/(I + \langle x \rangle)$. Then, I tried to show $I + \langle x \rangle $ is a prime ideal. But I am unable to prove it. Any help would be appreciated.

Just look at the proof here.

@Dietrich Burde, the OP seems to be asking a different question, his ideal $I_0$ is not a contraction, perhaps I am missing something...

@Dietrich burde, yes, but I am not able to see how to use that to answer his question... he is looking at the ideal in $R$ generated by constant terms of all elements in a prime ideal in $R[[x]]$

$R[[x]]/I\cong R[[x]]/(I_0,x)\cong R/I_0$ is a domain, hence $I_0$ is prime.

his ideal as stated is not $\langle I_0,x \rangle$.. or do you have reasoning for that?

No, this may be my mistake. I thought it is.

I disagree with the claim in your problem. Consider the ring $R = \mathbb{C}[y]$ which is a P.I.D. Then we have $R[[x]]$ is a U.F.D.
(see Ring of formal power series over a principal ideal domain is a unique factorisation domain).
The element $f = y^2 - x^3 \in R[[x]]$ is irreducible and hence generates a prime ideal, $I$. But $I_0$ in this case is the ideal generated by $y^2$ in $R$, which is not a prime ideal.

The answer seems correct. The exercise must be wrong then. Thank you!
